# How do I add an MSBuild .proj file to my solution?

Tags: msbuild

Does anyone know how to add a an MSBuild .proj file to my solution?

I was just given existing code from a vendor with a solution that references an MSBuild .proj file as one of its projects.  When I open the solution, the project shows as (unavailable).  It appears that I need to install some sort of project template to get this project to open correctly.  I installed the [Codeplex MSBuild Template](http://www.codeplex.com/MSBuildTemplate), but this doesn't appear to be it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need IDE support, it's possible to do this using MSBuild solution extension targets.

Create a file named "before.SolutionName.sln.targets" with the following code:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="CustomProject\CustomProject.proj">
      <AdditionalProperties>Configuration=$(Configuration); Platform=AnyCPU</AdditionalProperties>
      <Configuration>$(Configuration)</Configuration>
      <Platform>AnyCPU</Platform>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

When your solution is built at command line by MSBuild (ie/ build server) the custom MSBuild project will be pulled into the temporary in-memory project file that MSBuild converts the solution into.

Comment: Are the solution extension targets documented anywhere? I've just discovered the "before" and "after" target files by inspecting the .sln.metaproj.tmp file, but I can't find a reference to it on MSDN.

Comment: Not sure - I believe I got it by inspecting the metaproj.tmp file as well. It might be moot though - my understanding is that the next version of Visual Studio will finally use MSBuild for .sln files as well :)

Answer (score 2):

I actually got it to work! I re-started Visual Studio and still saw that the projects were unavailable after installing the MSBuild Template mentioned above.  I had to manually reload the projects.  That fixed the issue.