# How is dirs.proj used?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, msbuild

I'm afraid I may be asking a really dumb question, but I can't seem to find anything that makes this clear.  I usually work on smaller applications but am now working on a larger one with several assemblies in a baseline framework and several assemblies for a product line domain (with more to come).  I would like to manage the build by configuring MSBuild.  I've done a lot of online research (specifically with several MSDN articles I found) and now feel knowledgeable enough to be dangerous.

I understand that in csharp the *.csproj file can be unloaded and modified with properties, items, and targets to control the build process.  I also understand that I can import my own targets file to help separate and organize.  In this link though (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd483291.aspx) a multilevel project build is organized with node-level dirs.proj files.  This is confusing to me and has raised several questions I can't seem to find an answer to:

1. What is the difference in a *.proj and *.csproj file?
2. Can a *.proj be setup in VS to load on Build with F6 or does using this require use of the command prompt only? (i.e. "msbuild dirs.proj /t:Build").
3. Does dirs.proj load automatically?  If so, my study-by is not working correctly, yet it does with command prompt.
4. Or am I overlooking something all the way around with "dirs.proj"  Maybe it's just a substitue name for one of the project *.csproj files?  If that was the case though there wouldn't have been a need for the root node's dirs.proj which from what I can tell doesn't have an actual project associated to it.

Anyways, I've seen dirs.proj mentioned in several forums regarding issues, but no where can I find how it's loaded or used in VS (outside of manual command prompt building which seems unreasonable if this is used to organize the build but the build won't really take a huge amount of time).  I'm hoping someone can help me achieve that a-ha moment with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: theres no fundamental difference as they are just msbuild files. visual studio looks at certain metadata/properties and determines how to load it.

Comment: Then how do you integrate it or set it up with the VS Solution to build?  And is "dirs.proj" then just common nomenclature for the "source tree" approach to configuring large builds?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309255/how-do-i-add-an-msbuild-proj-file-to-my-solution

Comment: it depends on what it contains.

Comment: hmmm... use a project template?  I'll give that a try and let you know.

Comment: I took a look at the template and found the following... <StartArguments>%0\..\..\..\Build.proj</StartArguments> in the property group for the build configuration declaration and   <ItemGroup><None Include="Build.proj" /> </ItemGroup> in the *.csproj.  So from what I can tell it's just triggering the consumer *.proj from the solution's *.csproj.  But from what I understood in the article, there would be a dirs.proj not associated to a project at the root level.  Does that mean then there's supposed to be an empty *.csproj?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Dirs.proj is an MSBuild convention typically used when dealing with very large source trees (> than 20 projects).  I've worked with Microsoft engineers at a previous company and the dirs.proj convention appears to be one that Microsoft developed and uses internally to manage very large source trees.

A very good implementation reference for this is the [Python Tools for Visual Studio](https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS) project on <s>CodePlex</s> GitHub.

The [link you shared by Sayed Ibrahim Sashimi](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd483291.aspx) is a very good explanation of the reasoning behind the msbuild paradigm, but it doesn't do a very good job of showing a practical example of how it works.  The Python Tools project is an outstanding reference for this.

The idea behind using this paradigm is simple.  I'd wager a guess that most .NET software engineers work on somewhat limited-scale projects that don't deal with more than 5-10 projects at a time, and they manage these projects in Visual Studio via Solution (.sln) files.  They may even instruct their build system to run builds on the .sln.  This works fine until you start thinking about scaling your product into or combining it with something larger, such as a platform with many, many projects.  Solution files are not MSBuild files and as such they are not extensible like MSBuild is and they suffer massive performance penalties when dealing with large numbers of projects.

From an MSBuild perspective, dirs.proj stands in for Visual Studio .sln files.  The difference, however, is that dirs.proj don't just include .csproj (and the like) as .sln do, rather, they can include *source subtrees* (e.g. other nested dirs.proj).  So, building the root dirs.proj can result in the entire source tree being built, or building a nested dirs.proj will result in that subtree being built.

Therefore, the paradigm encourages you to look at your source as a series of interdependent nodes organized into features or product areas.  That way, engineers can work on different source subtrees in very large projects without having to deal with the entire source tree, as you would have to with a VS solution.

Using this paradigm also carries certain benefits that don't come with .sln files.  For example, if one project references a project from another, separate subtree, msbuild will build that reference first, automatically.  Additionally, your source nodes can carry their own build settings, allowing them to be built dynamically using different build settings based on build scenario.  For example, under one scenario a SharePoint source subtree needs WSP packaging, a C# subtree needs to be built without .pdb, a DB subtree needs to generate dacpacs, and the entire source tree needs to sign their assemblies using myCorp.snk and set build output to the $(buildRoot)\Output directory.

dirs.proj aren't opened via visual studio - they're built on the command line using msbuild.  The only pain point is that the files have to be hand-curated.

So, long answer short take a look at the Python Tools project and see how they're using dirs.proj.  Note how the entire source tree has common settings managed by Common.Build.settings, and how msbuild properties in this .settings file are used in the various .csproj files.

Comment: My project has a packages.proj, a solutions.proj and a dirs.proj
Along with this, there is an App.sln.
If I go in one level into the Solutions folder from here, there is a AppSolution.csproj 
I am confused about what the build order should be.
Generally, I do the Solution.proj first and then the packages.proj/.
Not sure where the dirs.proj lies in this order.